# Binding a certificate or redirecting root domain to www

Tags: azure

I configured Azure app service managed SSL certificate which is bound to my app service domain www.mydomain.io (IP SSL Binding). I want my root domain.io to redirect to www.mydomain.io or bind it as well to the same certificate. Can I configure this in the Azure Portal or at my domain provider (GoDaddy)? Or do I need to purchase a separate SLL certificate for my root domain?

I tried configure web.config in the following way but without luck:

```
 <rule name="Redirect old-domain to new-domain" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^https://mydomain.io$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mydomain.io/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
```

What happends is that the redirection does not occur instead it navigates to the Azure app service undir the root domain mydomain.io resulting in"Your connection is not secure" since the root domain is not bound to a certificate.

Is the web.config rule maybe not correctly written for this condition?

Comment: Hi @msestak thanks for your suggestion and link. I tried modifying the web.config file. See the updated question.

Comment: Thanks @msestak this worked. If you like you can copy your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need SSL certificate for domain.io. On domain.io app service you can simply configure URL redirect like stackoverflow.com/a/18005525/1443361

To redirect domain.io to https://mydomain.io change line

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.io$" />
```